# Maven read Ubuntu repository with windows developer machine

Tags: maven

We have our developer machines installed in a secure environment(say A) without internet access. We can move our .m2/repository folder created on the internet machine(say B) to a folder on a linux machine in the secured ENV and use that folder as a repository. Developers work on Windows in the same environment. the settings.xml looks like the below.

```
   <mirror>
      <id>repo1</id>
      <name>Local proxy of central repo</name>
      <url>file:////**%Linux_IP%**/maven/repository2</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>

 <servers>
    <server>
      <id>repo1</id>
      <username>uname</username>
      <password>pwd</password>            
    </server>
  </servers>
```

Error thrown:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5
>   from/to repo1 (file:////**%Linux_IP%**/maven/repository2): Repository
>   path \%Linux_IP%\maven\repository2 does not exist, and cannot be
>   created.

The above works fine if the repository is also on a windows machine but fails when the folder is on a Linux machine. As this is an initial release with very minor requirements, the org is not looking for a Nexus/Artifactory as an option at least for an year. Thanks!

Comment: Why you use 4 slashes? i thin 2 are enough: `file://`

Comment: @Jens I have tried with four slashes for windows and two for Linux but none works.

Answer (score 0):

Run a Nexus or Artifactory server. You can use it without internet connection and it has a nice, os independent way of managing the artifacts.

We do this ourselves. Our internal Nexus is disconnected from external repositories. If the developers need additional artifacts, we copy them from an external Nexus into our internal one.

Comment: Yes, Truly understand that we should run a Nexus or Artifactory but we do have a very little sized repo slated for the initial release. The org might want to invest/do this probably after an year.